# arima (0,1,0). How can I interpret it in this case?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

I was predicting time series using auto.arima () in R and I found something I don't know how to interpret.

For a certain number of time series, auto.arima () indicated that the best arima model was ARIMA (0,1,0)

[image]

**And as you can see, the prediction is a constant line.
Why is this happening? what interpretation can i give to the line?**

PD: about my time series: they are series of 38 data, seasonal with data grouped into quarters of the year

Comment: Yes!, what does it mean?

Comment: The two answers in the linked thread explain what a random walk is briefly. In addition, you may search online and will find plenty of material about it; it is a very well known stochastic process.

Comment: ok, i will search about it, thanks!